# Cannot Select Frames in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I know this question has been asked several times, but I haven't been able to figure out my issue.  I'm trying to select the 'fraHeader' frame but all I can get is 'Unable to locate element' errors. I'm using Webdriver with Java

Things I've tried:

1. using driver.findElement to find the frame, then driver.switchTo to switch to it - that doesn't work.  I consistently get 'Unable to locate element'.
2. I have tried using xpath, id and name to locate the frames, but none work.
3. recording the actions using Selenium IDE and exporting to Java - that gives me: // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | fraHeader | ]]
4. inserting mydriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); incase the code is running too fast.  That also does not help.

Here is my website code:

```
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
    <meta http-equiv= "pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <link rel="P3Pv1" href="/w3c/p3p.xml">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/frameset.js"></script>
</head>
<frameset id='masterFrameset' rows='130,*,25' border='0' framespacing='0' frameborder='no' onload=''>
    <frame name='fraHeader' noresize scrolling='no' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' frameborder='no' src='/header-default.jsp'>
    <frame name='fraBody' noresize scrolling='auto' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' frameborder='no' src='/control/store/login'>
    <frame name='fraFooter' noresize scrolling='no' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' frameborder='no' src='/footer-default.jsp'>
</frameset>
</html>
&#0149;
```

I'm new to Selenium and appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you trying to access any other element after switching to frame, for which it is showing error ?

Comment: My end goal is to: driver.findElement(By.tagName("fraHeader")); then driver.switchTo().frame("fraHeader");  I can find the element, but the problem is that I cannot switch to the frame.  So to answer your question, I'm not accessing any other elements after because I cannot get past the switchTo command.

Comment: I was able to figure this out by first switching to defaultContent: 
driver.findElement(by.tagName("fraHeader")); 
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("fraHeader"));
Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Good work.. You figured it out yourself.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to use WebDriverWait to wait for the frame to be visible. What you tried was implicit wait, explicit wait might be a worth try.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);  
WebElement iframe = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("masterFrameset"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().frame("masterFrameset");
```

or if the iframe is first one?

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @nilesh has suggested, you can also use the below code to **wait for frame to appear and switch to it**:

```
//Wait for 30 seconds for the frame with name "fraHeader" to appear and then switch to it.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("fraHeader"));
```

Comment: Neither of the suggestions have worked for me.  Both lead to a timeout error.  driver.findElement(By.tagName("fraHeader")); is successful, but I cannot switch to that element.  Is it possible to use driver.switchTo() with any other method besides a frame?